# How to reload the html page without refreshing the total page?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to reload the div but not refresh, I already have tried using .load() in Jquery

Comment: Use ajax to get the data and update the div

Comment: simple example how to do it,i am begineer

Comment: use AJAX to perform this https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp

Comment: _"I already have tried using .load() in Jquery"_ What was result?

Comment: no it didn't worked for me

Answer (score 0):

**Ajax with Jquery**

```
    $.ajax({url: "http://www.mywebsite.com/getResults", success: function(result){
        //update your div with result here
    }});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   function callThisFn(id)
   {    
     var p_url= 'a.html'
     jQuery.ajax({
     type: "GET",             
     url: p_url,
     success: function(data) {
       $('#summary').html(data);

    }
 });    
}
```

summary is the id of your div where you want to display html content.

Answer (score 0):

In angular context, if you want to refresh one page, use $route.reload() inside page's controller. It will safely refresh single page without losing context data of angular environment.

Sample Code:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $route) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
    $route.reload();
});
```